# Server join log displaying "${guild.name}" instead of the guild name

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to log  when my bot is added to servers, but the code I have just displays "New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!" in chat instead of the guild name, guild id, and guild members. Does anyone know how to fix it?

````
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
client.channels.cache.get('774529558044344333').send('New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!');
    })```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ordinary strings (with normal quotation signs) instead of literal templates (uses ` sign). Replace double-quotes like that:

```
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
client.channels.cache.get('774529558044344333').send(`New guild joined: ${guild.name} (id: ${guild.id}). This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
})
```